# Page unresponsive after modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

A have a webapp developed with Spring boot and thymeleaf a s front end.
We display all the groups available to review. Once user clicks a group we list documents in it tabular form and once user clicks on and document we provide its details. All these I am handling through ajax call and defining on click method. Once user gets to detail section they are provided with more details on that document where they can go and modify or add more through modal. Below is the modal

```
      <!-- Modal start-->
    <div id="editModal" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 id="pTitle" class="modal-title">Edit</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row" id="firstNameRow">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-4">First Name: </label>
                            <input class="col-sm-8" type="text" id="firstName" maxlength="32" onkeydown="return validateInputFields(this,event)"/>
                            <span class="text-danger" style="display:none;float: right;" id="firstNameError">First name is required.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="middleNameRow">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label for="middleName" class="col-sm-4">Middle Name: </label>
                            <input  class="col-sm-8" type="text" id="middleName" maxlength="32" onkeydown="return validateInputFields(this,event)"/>
                            <span class="text-danger" style="display:none;float: right;" id="middleNameError"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row has-danger" id="lastNameRow">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-4">Last Name: </label>
                            <input  class="col-sm-8 is-invalid" type="text" id="lastName" maxlength="32" onkeydown="return validateInputFields(this,event)" />
                            <div class="text-danger" style="display:none;float: right;" id="lastNameError" >Last name is required.</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" th:onclick="'save();'" id="saveButton"  data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal end-->
```

And here is my save function:

```
       function saveParty(){
var hasError = validateParty();
if(!hasError){
    //To close the modal and get back to the previous screen
    document.getElementById("saveButton").setAttribute("data-dismiss","modal");
    var data = loadPartyDetails();
    var objectID = $("#objectID").val();
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/saveDetails/" + objectID + "/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(result) {
        $("#detailsPanel").html(result);
        document.getElementById("successMsgParties").style.display="";
        $('#successMsgParties').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});

}
```

}

The call to make modal open:

```
            <td class="text-center"><a th:id="${iter.index + 1}" onclick="populateModal(this);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"></a></td>
```

And all this has been working fine. But sometimes all of sudden the whole page hangs up, I cant scroll I cant click on the links and have to refresh the page to continue. There are no errors on the console and have compare the response when the screen freeze and when it doesn't and there is no difference. At this point I am lost on where to look for and what could be the issue. Any directions will be appreciated.

Update: So I found that modal-open class was added but not getting remove when the screen froze, so I added below in my javascript. It does unable to page to scroll but all the links on the page are still disabled.

```
      $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
```

Alright, I found one more thing, below div element stays there whenever screen freeze. How can I found out which div element is this?

```
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

Any guidelines on how to close the modal appropriately?

Comment: Sounds like a backdrop remained somewhere... Right-click on the part where clicks don't work, and check if "Inspect" has something to say. It will probably find a fullscreen div that covers everything and hasn't been hidden for some reason. Not sure if this is the case, just a feeling.

Comment: This looks like bootstrap. Are you opening the modal by the data api event? I.e. does your button that opens the modal have `data-modal` attribute? Either way your not closing the modal correctly.

Comment: @Cue - It does have data-modal attribute, is there any specific rule on how to close the modal? I am closing it before making ajax call.

Comment: @dkellner I have "inspect" and reviewed div when it works and when it doesn't all looks same.

Comment: @ILRNew Look outside the div, modal backdrops tend to be at the very beginning or the very end of the body contents. Save both full HTMLs and do a compare with WinMerge. If this doesn't help, maybe I suspected the wrong thing.

Comment: @ILRNew I don’t see anywhere in your code where you programmatically dismiss #editModal within your Ajax call.

Comment: Should             $( ".modal-backdrop" ).remove(); remove that element? It's not doing so..

Comment: @ILRNew It should. And there must be a reason why it doesn't. List $(".modal-backdrop") into your console to see if it finds the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the below div element being added which is making screen freeze. I have to hide this through javascript.

```
                  <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically dismissing a Modal can be done using `$('#editModal').modal('hide')`

So either the modal is dismissed using the close or cancel button or from the Javascript using the method I shared.